# Different constraints for 3.5 inch and 4 inch

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

My label is positioned with a distance of `50px` to the bottom of my **4 inch** screen.

Now I want to use constraints so that this label is positioned `30px` to the bottom on a **3.5 inch** screen. Is this possible using auto layout and constraints?

When I set a **bottom-constraint** to `30px`, the label is also positioned `30px` to bottom on a **4 inch screen**. Basically I want to reduce the space between my objects so that everything fits to the **3.5 inch** screen.

Comment: Your label got a fix height?

Comment: I asked a similar question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600539/ios-auto-layout-flexible-margins

Comment: Can you post how you have achieved this? Manually adding/modify constraints for 3.5 nad 4" inch during view load?

Answer (score 0):

If you want conditional constraints, you need to add the constraints manually (the bottom constraint at least, but I don't recommend using both code and IB for constraints).

Add a test for device and set the bottom value based on that:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480) {
        distanceToBottom = 30; // pre-iPhone 5
    }

    if(result.height == 568) {
        distanceToBottom = 50; // iPhone 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it to be proportional to the screen size, you can make the constraint proportional:

```
// this constraint positions the label at the bottom of its superview
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label 
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:label.superview
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1
                                                                     constant:0];

// move it up by 6% of the superview's height
bottomConstraint.constant = -(label.superview.bounds.size.height * .06);
```

A couple of things to note:

1) You'll have to set this constraint's constant when the view has been laid out, so `label.superview` has a height. `updateConstraints` is a good place for this.

2) The constant is a fixed value, so it won't automatically update if the bounds of `layout.superview` change, for example on rotation. You'll want to make sure the percentage calculation happens again in that case. The best place to do that depends on how your view is laid out and what would cause it to resize.

Alternatively, you could base the constant on the window height, as @Handsomeguy suggests:

```
bottomConstraint.constant = -([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * .06);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple way is to use "proportions" within storyboard.
Specify constraints, for example, for width, height, and horizontal align.
For vertical align, which will be your case, you use proportions.
The idea is this: "however height the screen is, pin the bottom of label to the bottom of superview with a certain value", and you don't need to calculate that value.

[Proportion set in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8tV1.png)

With such values, I specify that label's bottom is always 95% of superview's bottom (Btw, 'bottom' is another way of saying 'maximum Y value within a frame', which is same as, 'y' + 'height').

The logged 'bottom' values of the label for different devices are:

```
"3.5" = 457   (427 + 30)
"4"   = 540.5 (510.5 + 30)
"4.7" = 634.5 (604.5 + 30)
"5.5" = 700.3 (670.3 + 30)
```